# Is it possible to extend a method within an extended scala class?

Tags: scala, gatling

Assume I have the following scala classes, is it possible to extend a function on SecondClass and add more code to it? (possibly chained to another function within the function i'd like to extend)

```
package io.gatling.http.check
class FirstClass {

  def login() = {
    exec(http("Login")
      .post("anonymous/login")
      .body(ElFileBody("rest/UserAnonymousLogin.json")).asJson
}
}
```

I would like to extend the login function with the following (.check(status is 200)

```
class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

  def login() = {
     .check(status is 200))
}
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: it is possible, but what is `status` here? it's not defined in your code

Comment: .check(status is 200) is a chain that is supposed to go after .body. So after my wanted extention of login, it would look like:  exec(http("Login")
      .post("anonymous/login")
      .body(ElFileBody("rest/UserAnonymousLogin.json").check(status is 200))).asJson

Comment: does that compile? i don't get where `status` is defined in either example

Comment: status is part of package io.gatling.http.check and it compiles if you import it. The functionality of the extension in my example is not relevant.. my question is what is the syntax to allow this type of function chain extension.

Comment: sure, though it always helps people answer questions here when everything is defined, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I've added more information and the needed package for it to compile.

Comment: @PloniStacker, there are questions where reproducibility helps, and there are questions where reproducibility doesn't have anything to do with the matter in the question. Regarding this question, a more defined  `def login() = println("Reproduce me")`, woulldn't have helped at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [`checks`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/3db4b40f5e238d5159a5756eddf78608310dff45/gatling-http/src/main/scala/io/gatling/http/request/builder/HttpRequestBuilder.scala#L68) method accepts a variable number of `HttpCheck`, that is, `HttpCheck*`

```
def check(checks: HttpCheck*): HttpRequestBuilder
```

consider refactoring `FirstClass` to

```
  class FirstClass {
    def login(checks: HttpCheck*) = {
      exec(http("Login")
        .post("anonymous/login")
        .body(ElFileBody("rest/UserAnonymousLogin.json")).asJson
        .check(checks: _*)
      )
    }
  }
```

Note how by default we pass no checks when calling `(new FirstClass).login()`.

Now derived classes could pass in a checks to be performed like so

```
  class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    def loginWithStatusCheck() = {
      super.login(status is 200)
    }
  }
```

Note we are not actually overriding `FirstClass.login` here.

Another approach instead of overriding could be functional composition, for example, we break down the problem into smaller functions

```
  val buildClient: String => Http = http(_)
  val buildPostRequest: Http => HttpRequestBuilder = _.post("anonymous/login").body(ElFileBody("rest/UserAnonymousLogin.json")).asJson
  val checkStatus: HttpRequestBuilder => HttpRequestBuilder = _.check(status is 200)
```

and then compose them

```
exec((buildClient andThen buildPostRequest andThen checkStatus)("Login"))
```

Now we can simply add further steps to the composition instead of worrying about class hierarchies and overriding.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd use `def login(checks: HttpCheck*)` and `super.login(status is 200)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
class X {
  def go(a: Int) = ???
}

class Y extends X {
  override def go(a: Int) = {
    val u = super.go(a)
    // do things with `u` and return whatever
  }
}
```

You'll need to do a little refactoring to get your code in this shape. I envisage

```
class FirstClass {
  def body = ElFileBody("rest/UserAnonymousLogin.json")
  // stuff that calls `body`
}

class SecondClass {
  override def body = super.body.check(status is 200)
  // no need to redefine stuff as it's inherited from `FirstClass`
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you very much! Your answer also made me realise that I did not ask the question correctly as I am actually trying to chain a method on an object that is not returned by the function, allow me to use the following example:

Comment: `class  Test{

  def login() = {
    http("Login")
      .post("login")
      .body(ElFileBody("Login.json")).asJson
      .check(status is 200)
  }

  def login2() = {
    exec(http("Login")
      .post("login")
      .body(ElFileBody("Login.json")).asJson
      .check(status is 200))
  }

}

class Test2 extends Test{

  override def login = super.login.check()

  override def login2 = super.login2.check
}`

Comment: stack overflow refuses to show my answer as code :(  anyhow, Example login2 wont compile as I am actually trying to chain on http while I am actually chaining it on exec. I do want to have the exec on the original method but add another verification along the way when needed, is there any way around it?